What would be the recommended season viewing order for the '90s animated Marvel universe for someone new?
So with the recent release of X-Men '97, I figured it would be a good idea to rewatch through the 90s animated Marvel Universe, but my wife will be watching as well.
Since she is someone who only has some knowledge regarding Marvel, I figured it would be best to simplify things and watch season by season.
Shows I am including:

Spider-Man: The Animated Series
Iron Man: The Animated Series
The Incredible Hulk: The Animated Series
Fantastic Four: The Animated Series
Silver Surfer: The Animated Series
X-Men: The Animated Series
Spider-Man Unlimited
Avengers: United They Stand
X-Men '97


I would go with release order, as most if not all of them did not have cross overs in stories that I can remember.

@Brad There were a few: the Hulk vs The Thing in Fantastic Four, the Spider-Man/X-Men crossover, Daredevil crossed over with both Spider-Man and the Fantastic Four. Pretty sure Hulk and Iron Man crossed over, and War Machine in Spider-Man the Animated Series
